# Strange behavior of RecyclerView after removing item

Tags: android, android-animation, android-recyclerview

I've tried to add some swipe functionality to the RecyclerView. Basically, when user swipes item more than some range and releases it, item slides to the end and is removed. So far, so good.

On small number of items (less than screen height) everything works perfectly, but with bigger number of items weird behavior begins. When some item is removed in the middle of the list, one item, which is right above the screen top, and one item, which is right under the screen bottom, "disappear" too, leaving empty spaces.

I did investigation around this problem. The problem seems to be with changing `TranslationX` of the item's view before its removal. My basic code to remove item:

```
view.animate()
    .translationX(view.getWidth())
    .setDuration(500)
    .alpha(0)
    .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            removeItem(position);
        }
    });
```

Once I've accidentally changed `TranslationX` value to the number smaller than item's width. This showed that this two items don't disappear, but rather get the same `TranslationX` value as the removed item have. Actually, if I don't animate removal, but just set item's `TranslationX` and then remove it, the problem remains.

Problem can be solved in this way, but it is dirty solution which does not explain the nature of such behavior:

```
view.animate()
    .translationX(view.getWidth())
    .setDuration(500)
    .alpha(0)
    .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            view.setTranslationX(0f); // Dirty solution
            removeItem(position);
        }
    });
```

Here is how the problem looks like (if `TranslationX` is smaller than width):
[image: Screenshots of the problem]

I created a simple project just with fragment and adapter to remove any possible external influences.

**ItemsFragment.java**

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v7.widget.DefaultItemAnimator;
import android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ItemsFragment extends Fragment implements ItemsAdapter.ItemsAdapterClickListener {
    private RecyclerView mItemsList;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_items, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        mItemsList = (RecyclerView) getView().findViewById(R.id.items_list);

        mItemsList.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mItemsList.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        mItemsList.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

        List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
            items.add("Item " + (i + 1));
        }

        ItemsAdapter adapter = new ItemsAdapter(items, this);
        mItemsList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mItemsList = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClicked(final int position) {
        LinearLayoutManager manager = (LinearLayoutManager) mItemsList.getLayoutManager();
        int first = manager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
        final View view = mItemsList.getChildAt(position - first + 1);

        view.animate()
                .translationX(view.getWidth() / 2)
                .setDuration(500)
                .alpha(0)
                .withEndAction(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        //view.setTranslationX(0f);
                        removeItem(position);
                    }
                });

        //view.setTranslationX(500);
        //removeItem(position);
    }

    public void removeItem(int position) {
        ItemsAdapter adapter = (ItemsAdapter) mItemsList.getAdapter();

        adapter.removeItem(position);
        adapter.notifyItemRemoved(position);
    }
}
```

**ItemsAdapter.java**

```
import android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

public class ItemsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ItemsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<String> mItems;
    private ItemsAdapterClickListener mListener;

    public ItemsAdapter(List<String> items, ItemsAdapterClickListener listener) {
        this.mItems = items;
        this.mListener = listener;
    }

    public interface ItemsAdapterClickListener {
        public void onItemClicked(int position);
    }

    public String removeItem(int position) {
        return mItems.remove(position);
    }

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private TextView mTitle;

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.item_title);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.items_list_item, parent, false);

        final ViewHolder holder = new ViewHolder(view);

        view.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mListener != null)
                    mListener.onItemClicked(holder.getPosition());
            }
        });

        return holder;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.mTitle.setText(mItems.get(position));
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mItems.size();
    }
}
```

Do you have any explanations better than bug in RecyclerView?